# Setup alternative DNS entry while DNSimple is down for DDoS?

Tags: domain-name-system, ddos

We have an app with domains registered with DNSimple. DNSimple is undergoing a DDoS attack resulting in the domains not resolving.

Is it possible to set up a new DNS entry with another provider in the interim without having access to DNSimple to edit the records?

Comment: Thanks!  Rest of story: was able to login to DNSimple via IP address. Setup Secondary DNS on separate site. That requires adding an NS record to primary server.  DNSimple doesn't allow NS records for domains or subdomains with CNAME records.  All my domains have CNAME records.  By which time DDoS was resolved. Presumably DNSimple will offer a secondary DNS service soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no access at all to your existing DNS provider, your only option would be to delegate the domain to new nameservers through your registrar. But there would be a propagation delay for that. You might as well do this and you can always switch it back later.

I'd recommend you try out Cloudflare. They have free DNS hosting and will duplicate the records from the existing domain for you. Plus they're very protected from ddos.

Answer (score 1):

No as the registrar is not reachable (as dnssimple is ddos), as it hold your dns entry. You cant change the nameserver

Comment: I got an minus score, but to transfert a DNS entry from a registrar to another you need access to the first to be able to make it. (and dnssimple is DDoS....)

Comment: Typically it are the name servers of a provider that are under attack, their website and customer portal may still be available allowing you to update your DNS servers in TLD registry. Alternatively not all TLD require approval from the current registrar either, they may contact the owner and/or technical contacts directly with an email message to validate the domain transfer request.

Comment: @HBruijn, I agree with you, but the OP does not have access, thus asked if its possible without accessing to change the record, thus why i answered no

Answer (score 1):

dnsimple now support Secondary DNS. So each record will be copied to your secondary DNS automatically.

[image]

If your provider is Dyn, DNSMadeEasy, or EasyDNS, you’re one click away from completing the configuration. Otherwise, select the custom option.

[image]

> Once Secondary DNS has been correctly set up for a particular domain, every zone change will be replicated on the Secondary DNS provider. All existing records will be copied over, including standard records and DNSimple custom records like ALIAS and URL. These will be resolved and the resulting value will be pushed to the secondary.

Further details mentioned in the [secondary-dns-blog](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/secondary-dns).